# Creating a subplot of box plots with free y axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this toy dataset that I want to plot by group:

```
df_plots = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D'],\
                         'Value':[1,1.2,1.4,1.3,16,18,16,19,43,47,42,55,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6]})
df_plots

    Group   Value
0   A   1.0
1   A   1.2
2   A   1.4
3   A   1.3
4   B   16.0
5   B   18.0
6   B   16.0
7   B   19.0
8   C   43.0
9   C   47.0
10  C   42.0
11  C   55.0
12  D   0.2
13  D   0.4
14  D   0.3
15  D   0.6
```

I want to create boxplots per group, but when I use this code, the plot minimizes one of the groups due to the size of the values:

```
df_plots.groupby('Group').boxplot(column = 'Value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So I want the y-axis to be scale free, so I try to create subplots with this code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,6)) 

for i, k in enumerate(df_plots.groupby('Group').groups.keys()):
    group = df_plots.groupby('Group').get_group(k)
    group.boxplot(ax=axes[i], return_type='axes')
```

But I get an error: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'boxplot'`

Please, could you help me with my plot?

Comment: You mistyped ``'axes'`` in the last line of your code. You typed ``'axs'`` instead. And try this: ``fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,6), sharey=False)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sharey=False` to separate the y-axis scales, and `flatten` the `axes` to loop over the `(2,2)` subplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,6), sharey=False)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i, g in enumerate(df_plots.groupby('Group')):
    g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i])
```

Alternatively, `seaborn` is useful for this kind of task:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(data=df_plots, y='Value', 
            col='Group', col_wrap=2, 
            kind='box', sharey=False)
```

Comment: Thank you @Brendan, it worked fine! Just a question, why this element has a fixed index: `g[1]`?

Comment: @Alexis Iterating over `df_plots.groupby('Group')` returns a `tuple` of the group ID in the first position (`g[0]`) and that group's dataframe in the second position (`g[1]`) -- so you use `g[1]` to access the dataframe group by group. If you wanted to title the subplots with the group ID, you could pass `g[0]` to the title. If you want to check this for yourself, add `print(type(g))`, `print(g[0])`, and `print(g[1])` to the loop above to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the strategy of passing values for the tuples will help me to infer what's happening. Have a great day @Brendan!